# Returning the rest of a string in c after the first white space

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to return a the rest of a string after the first white space.

```
"I had a bad day"
```

should return

```
"had a bad day"
```

This is what I have so far

```
char* next_word(char* str){
    char s[100];
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            index = i+1;
            for(index; index < strlen(str); index++){
                s[counter] = str[index];
                counter = counter + 1;

            }
            s[index] = '\0';
            return s;

        }


    }
    return index;
}
```

I'm looping through the char* str and finding the index of the first empty space then from there I've made another loop to print out the rest of the string starting at index + 1. For some reason when I writes s[counter] = str[index], I don't believe that its copying the char from str to s.
When I try to return s after the loop I don't get anything. Is it possible to add char to the empty char s[100] then return the full string as s?
Thank You

Comment: `next_word()` function return a char* as well as int? Is your code compiling? Also, `s` is a local variable. So, returning `s` is undefined behavior.

Comment: don't you get **any** diagnostics messages from the compiler?!

Comment: @kuro, my code compiles and i think I’m only returning s which is a char s

Comment: @serenitynow13, then what about `return index` statement in your code? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

Your `next_word()` function is returning a local (to the function) variable which results in a undefined behavior. You must take `s` (in your case) as input or malloc a character buffer in the function. Then you can do the copying. I prefer you go for the first alternative and do not forget to check the length of the input string, so that you do not cross the size while copying.

Also, the `next_word()` returns `index` when no space found? That is clearly a mistake and your code will fail to compile.

For the code, you can just break from the first loop whenever you find the first space and from there you can continue with copying.

Answer (score 3):

You should not return `s` as it is a local variable on the stack. You could simply return a pointer into the `str` argument since `str` remains valid at the time of return.

```
#include <string.h>

const char* TheString = "I had a bad day";

const char* stringAfterBlank(const char* str)
{
    const char* blank = strchr(str, ' ');
    if (blank != NULL)
    {
        return ++blank;
    }
    return "";
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* restOfTheString = stringAfterBlank(TheString);
    // restOfTheString is "had a bad day" pointing into TheString
}
```

If you need a copy of the string then you can use `strdup`. If you do then don't forget to `free`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I'm trying to do this using only stdio and stdlib.

Comment: `strchr` is a pretty simple function that you can easily replace with your own code (search for 'strchr implementation').

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return your local variable. The easiest way to accomplish what you want is operating on pointers.

There is solution using only stdio.h, as you wanted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* next_word(char* str);

int main()
{
    char* arg = "I had a bad day!";
    //Print every "next_word"
    char* words = arg;
    do{
        printf("%s\n", words);
    } while(words = next_word(words));
}

char* next_word(char* str)
{
   while(*str != '\0'){
       if(*str++ == ' ')
           return str;
   }
   return NULL;
}
```